# Substract every value in matrices stored in a list of a list from 1

Tags: r, matrix, purrr

I have several lists stored in a list. Each list contains eight matrices. The matrices within every list are of equal length, but the length differs between the lists. Here´s a little example to give you an idea:

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 1), 3, 3)
b <- matrix(c(1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 1), 3, 3, byrow = T)
c <- matrix(c(1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 1, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 1, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 1), 4, 4)
d <- matrix(c(1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 1, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 1, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 1), 4, 4, byrow = T)

lst1 <- list(a = a, b = b)
lst2 <- list(c = c, d = d)

lst <- list(lst1 = lst1, lst2 = lst2)

lst
$lst1
$lst1$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.4  0.7
[2,]  0.2  1.0  0.8
[3,]  0.3  0.6  1.0

$lst1$b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.2  0.3
[2,]  0.4  1.0  0.6
[3,]  0.7  0.8  1.0


$lst2
$lst2$c
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1.00 0.25 0.45 0.65
[2,] 0.10 1.00 0.50 0.70
[3,] 0.15 0.35 1.00 0.75
[4,] 0.20 0.40 0.60 1.00

$lst2$d
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1.00  0.1 0.15  0.2
[2,] 0.25  1.0 0.35  0.4
[3,] 0.45  0.5 1.00  0.6
[4,] 0.65  0.7 0.75  1.0
```

What I want to do is to substract every value in every matrix from 1 and replace the original values with the calculated ones. As outcome I want to get:

```
$lst1
$lst1$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.0  0.6  0.3
[2,]  0.8  0.0  0.2
[3,]  0.7  0.4  0.0

$lst1$b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.0  0.8  0.7
[2,]  0.6  0.0  0.4
[3,]  0.3  0.2  0.0


$lst2
$lst2$c
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0.00 0.75 0.55 0.35
[2,] 0.90 0.00 0.50 0.30
[3,] 0.85 0.65 0.00 0.25
[4,] 0.80 0.60 0.40 0.00

$lst2$d
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0.00  0.9 0.85  0.8
[2,] 0.75  0.0 0.65  0.6
[3,] 0.55  0.5 0.00  0.4
[4,] 0.35  0.3 0.25  0.0
```

I thought I can do it with anything similar to `lst %>% modify(~. - 1)`, but the other way arround `lst %>% modify(~1 - .)`, but this does not work. I realised it´s much easier to subtract values from the matrix than subtracting every value from the matrix from a value... In my little example I just created a 3x3 and 4x4 matrix only containing 1s, subtracted the matrices a-d from it and stored the again in the lists:

```
e <- matrix(1, 3, 3)
f <- matrix(1, 4, 4)

a <- e-a
b <- e-b
c <- f-c
d <- f-d

lst1 <- list(a = a, b = b)
lst2 <- list(c = c, d = d)

lst <- list(lst1 = lst1, lst2 = lst2)
```

Then I thought I can replace all the values in the matrices by 1s and substract these from the original matrices. However, I can´t manage it. Maybe you can help me out with a good purrr solution.

Thanks in advance!
Tobi

Comment: `lapply(lst, lapply, function(mat) 1 - mat)`

Comment: Or `rapply(lst, function(mat) 1 - mat, how = "replace")`

Comment: A `purrr` solution could be `lst %>% modify_depth(2, ~ 1 - .x)`

Comment: @Aurèle Why don't you post the comments as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, the above is now an answer.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply(lst, lapply, function(mat) 1 - mat)` or a `purrr` solution `lst %>% modify_depth(2, ~ 1 - .x)` will operate at the second level of nesting.

Alternatively, `rapply(lst, function(mat) 1 - mat, classes = "matrix", how = "replace")` will operate on matrix elements located at arbitrary levels of nesting.

---

Choosing the first or the second option depends on what the assumptions on the input structure are, how strictly they are checked beforehand, and the desired fallback behavior. Accordingly, some extra logic would have to be implemented separately.

Comment: Thank you Auréle! I'm new to the purrr package. I like it, but I'm often struggling with the right syntax or choosing the right function for my approach. Now I understand the modify_depth function and that's another great tool for my work.